# Type mismatch error occurs while casting string values to date type in MDX query with some blank rows

Tags: ssas, mdx, ssas-tabular, ssas-2012, mdx-query

I have a string-type dimension in my `SSAS` cube having the date values along with some blank values and please find the screenshot for your reference.

[image]

I am trying to convert these values into Date using the [CDate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/vba-functions-in-mdx-and-dax?view=sql-server-ver15) function in the `MDX` query. I have used the following MDX query which will return null when the value is either empty or null and returns the date value for valid values.

```
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[Company].[OrderDate] AS 'CASE WHEN ISEMPTY([Company].[OrderDate].CurrentMember.MemberValue) OR [Company].[OrderDate].CurrentMember.MemberValue = null THEN null Else CDate([Company].[OrderDate].CurrentMember.MemberValue) END' SELECT{
[Measures].[Company].[OrderDate]} ON COLUMNS ,Subset(NONEMPTY((
(Order((([Company].[OrderDate].[OrderDate].ALLMEMBERS)), CDate([Company].[OrderDate].CurrentMember.Member_Caption),ASC))),{[Measures].DefaultMember}),0,100) ON ROWS FROM [Model] CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING
```

However, When am trying to convert these string values into Date I am getting the **Type mismatch** error as shown in the following screenshot:

[image]

**Can anyone please suggest how to convert the string dimension values to date type when blank values are present in the dimension?**

Comment: Not an expert, but a bit concerning that there are multiple rows with what appear to be the same value in the dimension table.  Can you eliminate these (blank) values from the dimension?  If you cannot do this, what DATE value would you like to use instead of the blank that is present?